# NSUrl throws exception

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin.iOS app, I have this code:

```
using (var url = new NSUrl(uri))
{
    // some code
}
```

It was working before, but when I create the `new NSUrl(uri)` it throws an exception with the message:

> Could not initialize an instance of the type 'Foundation.NSUrl': the
> native 'initWithString:' method returned nil. It is possible to ignore
> this condition by setting ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to
> false.

My `uri` is something like this:
[https://myappdev.blob.core.windows.net/myimages/apples/auth0|5db82ec6a5ee570c97cd5465.jpg?1666895662894](https://myappdev.blob.core.windows.net/myimages/apples/auth0%7C5db82ec6a5ee570c97cd5465.jpg?1666895662894)

When I paste `uri` into my browser I get an image. (the url above is an example so you won't get an image if you try to download it)

Comment: have you searched on that error message?  There are numerous existing questions about it

Comment: Could this be help? [forms app device.openuri system exception in ios](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb5c14b2-293c-4e7a-be41-73168c3055f4/forms-app-deviceopenuri-system-exception-in-ios?forum=xamarinforms)

Comment: I did not find a solution in that link, or any where else I have searched.

Comment: Several of the hits I found suggest url encoding the url, which is essentially what @LiqunShen-MSFT suggests.  If you paste the url in the browser you will notice that the browser does this for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue in Xamarin.ios and get the same error.

I noticed that a special character "|" in your url. Seems the error was due to this special character.

And after I changed "|" to "%" then the error disappeared.